# Get Result from child_process.fork() and then Respond to the Client

Tags: node.js, express

I have a solid confusion regarding getting result from my child_process.fork() and then responding to the client.
Is the Node.js server while executing able to be responsive to more requests, i.e., let user could send any other requests to server while child_process is still in execution and user is able to get response of the latest request, is it correct?

Code for reference:

```
router.route('/analysis')
.get(function(req, res, next){
User.find({}, {'_id': true, 'are_you': true})
    .exec(function(err, user){
        if(err) return next(err);
        var child = child_process.fork(__dirname + '/analysis.js', [], {});
        child.send('Hi');
        child.on('message', message => {
            console.log('message from child:', message);
        });
        res.status(200).json(user);   //does here client puts other requests in event queue, until the child process executes completely and responds?
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's go through the key lines:

```
var child = child_process.fork(__dirname + '/analysis.js', [], {});
```

This line tells Node that you want to fork and it returns a `ChildProcess` to represent that action. However, the actual forking won't have happened yet as it's performed asynchronously. It won't wait for that to happen, your code will just keep running.

```
child.send('Hi');
```

Again nothing happens immediately, this will just queue up a message to send to the forked process. The `send` method should return `true` to indicate that your message has successfully been added to the queue but that's no guarantee it will actually be delivered. If you need feedback on whether the message makes it through you'd need to pass in a callback to `send`. This is all asynchronous so once again you're code continues to run the next line rather than waiting.

```
child.on('message', message => {
    console.log('message from child:', message);
});
```

This registers a listener for the `message` event on the `ChildProcess`. The registration happens immediately but it won't wait for a message to be received before carrying on running your code (to be clear, the code inside your callback won't be run until a message is received, for now it will be skipped and execution continues on the next line). Remember that the forking hasn't actually happened yet, all you're doing is interacting with a `ChildProcess` object that represents the soon-to-be-created child process. Again, everything is asynchronous so the code continues to run to the next line.

```
res.status(200).json(user);
```

Sends a response to the current request. The child process still hasn't been spawned, it's sitting in a queue waiting for your code to end. The request is now complete as far as Express is concerned and the client (i.e. browser) will soon receive the response. However, this doesn't mean that the child process will be thrown away. As soon as Node gets a chance it'll spawn the process and any messages or events should proceed just the same as if you hadn't responded to the request. The only thing you can't do is respond again.

All the actions you perform on your `ChildProcess` are asynchronous, so none of them actually does anything immediately, they just queue up as 'things to do'. As it is currently written, your code will respond to the HTTP request before the child process has spawned. If you want to send the response after you've got some result from your child process then you'd have to move the code for sending your response so that it is inside a callback for a suitable event of the `ChildProcess`.

Regarding your question about multiple requests coming in at the same time, it is entirely possible for that to happen and for multiple child processes to be forked concurrently. If your child process cannot cope with having multiple copies running at once (e.g. because they both need to write to the same file) then you'll need to prevent that from happening yourself, Node won't do it for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
It gives me lots of clarity about child processes.
So my code would be like this:
    https://jsfiddle.net/7Ln6cjem/
Now is this blocking other requests in queue?

Comment: @AvinashSharma No, it will not block other requests. It will wait for the child process to send a message before it responds to the HTTP request but other requests can be serviced while it's waiting. Only synchronous actions block, waiting for something to happen asynchronously does not.

Comment: Thanks for the information :) ...really a great help